# C# code for Mongo UpdateOneAsync using AddToSet

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Please could sombody help me with procedure Update  using AddToSet as parameter

my code looks like this :

```
var ls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var element in typeof(T).GetMembers())
        {
            var res = element.GetType().GetProperty(element.Name).GetValue(element.Name);
            ls.Add(element.Name, res.ToString());
        }


 var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
                                            Builders<T>.Filter.Where(filter),
                                            Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet(ls.Keys.ToString(), ls.Values));
```

What I have to put on first parameter insted of ls.key and ls.values?
Thanks

Comment: You have asked a similar question before. `AddToSet()` is used to modify a list atomically in the database. You're trying to do something else entirely, but it's not really clear what you want to accomplish. It seems as if you simply want to replace the document. Please add a description of what you actually want and make sure to read the documentation on what `$addToSet` does.

Comment: Actualy I try to update array of one document  but it not updated it , just add it to new one. If I try to add it separatly without model , it gave me erro when I try to search again on the document. My goal is to understand how method on C# works with mongoDb and could I update whole entity or not and how to updated many collection and array on document using C# pattern for that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following JSON in Mongo

```json
 "Settings" : [ 
        {
            "ChannelType" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Name" : "NxtOne",
                "Details" : "NxtOne Media Group",
               
            },
            "ChannelSubscribers" : ["20052"],
            "ChannelDays" : 90,
            "CreatedDate" : null,
            
        }
    ],
```

Example if you want to update  "ChannelSubscribers" and "CreatedDate" in mongo.
How will you do it with help of Builders?

Note:

- If you want update(or Add) "Subscribers" where Subscribers is list of
  Arrays,then **use `AddToSet`** operator.
- For the next item `CreatedDate` that is simply a property, then
  **use `Set`** operator.

For Adding Channel "Subscribers" to Array List(Use `AddToSet` opearator)

```cs
public async Task AddChannelSubscriberAsync(string accountId, short id, string userId)
 {

   var filter = BaseFilter(accountId) &
   Builders<Channel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Settings, y => y.ChannelType.Id == id);

    var update = Builders<Channel>.Update.AddToSet("${nameof(Channel.Settings)}.${nameof(Settings.ChannelSubscribers)}", userId);

    await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
 }
```

#For Removing value from "Subscribers" Array (Use **Pull** operator)

```cs
public async Task AddChannelSubscriberAsync(string accountId, short id, string userId)
 {

var filter = BaseFilter(accountId) &
Builders<Channel>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Settings, y => y.ChannelType.Id == id);
 var update = Builders<Channel>.Update.Pull("${nameof(Channel.Settings)}.${nameof(Settings.ChannelSubscribers)}", userId);

 await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
  }
```

For updating `CreatedDate` (Use `Set` operator)

```cs
public async Task UpdateCreatedDateAsync(string accountId, Settings settings)
 {

 var filter = BaseFilter(accountId) & Builders<Account>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Settings, y => y.ChannelType.Id == settings.ChannelType.Id);

 var update =Builders<Channel>.Update.Set("${nameof(Channel.Settings)}.$.{nameof(Settings.CreatedDate)}", settings.CreatedDate);

     await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
   }
```

Base Filter implementation:

```cs
 public FilterDefinition<Channel> BaseFilter(string accId)
 {
 return Builders<Channel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, accId) &
 Builders<Channel>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Status,(int)StatusEnum.ActiveChannel);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

After deep investigation I found solutiona and I will post it here to share knowledge

```
public class NeolineReorganizedMongoResult
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public List<string> DealerListAbout { get; set; }
}


public async Task<UpdateResult> Update(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
T  entity)
{

            if (entity._id == null)
                await Insert(entity);

            var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(
                                    Builders<T>.Filter.Where(filter),
                                    Builders<T>.Update.Set(x => x.dealer_code, entity.dealer_code));


            if (result.IsAcknowledged)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            return result;
}



var element = result.Result.Where(x => x.dealer_code.Trim() == "8888").FirstOrDefault();

        if (element == null) return;
        element.DealerListAbout = new List<string>
        {
            "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4" 
        };

        foreach (var item in element.DealerListAbout)
        {
            using (Task updated = list.UpdateSetProperty(x => x.dealer_code.Equals("8888"), element.DealerListAbout, item))
            {
                updated.Wait();
                if (!updated.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.Write("Success");
                    var value = list.SearchFor(x => x.dealer_code.Equals("5430")).Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Failed");
                }
            }
        }
```